# Fire multiple functions on resize events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to fire multiple functions when the window resizes. But only one function works at the time. Please correct this code.

```
function resize() {
   var $containerWidth = $(window).width();
    if ($containerWidth > 1140) {
        //code...
    }
   else {
         //code...
    }
}

resize();

function resizepos() {
   var topPosition = $('.redcus').offset().top;
   $('.blackcus').css('top',(topPosition+40)+'px');
}

resizepos();

$(window).resize(function(){
   resize();
   resizepos();
});
```

Comment: What problems did you find on the current code?

Comment: Cristik. Only one function work, rest of function not working. When i change function resizepos to resize. I will be work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try the code like this :

```
function resize() {
   var $containerWidth = $(window).width();
    if ($containerWidth > 1140) {
        //code...
    }
   else {
         //code...
    }
resizepos();
}
```

And try to change your function name when you calling it in jquery, ex "Allresize" and in the contents of Allresize function there is "resizepos" function. Don't use "resize" double, please check it again.

Sorry for the bad format, i can't handle it from my android.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really use jQuery but edit this if I'm wrong:

```
$(window).on('resize', resize);
$(window).on('resize', resizepos);
```